# Want to know what this mathematical operator does in R - %*%

Tags: r

I am new to R programming and while reading a book I came across this mathematical operation involving a matrix in R - "%*%". I could not understand what the following operation does. Can someone help me please?

```
> y
       [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   1      3
 [2,]   2      4
> y%*%y
       [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    7   15
 [2,]   10   22
>
```

Comment: It's matrix multiplication.  That's the result of the inner products of the rows of the first matrix with the columns of the second matrix.  See `?'%*%'`.

Comment: When I tried to understand it, I found the German Wikipedia images most intuitive: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrizenmultiplikation#Definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%*%` multiplies two matrices.

In your example:

```
        [,1]        [,2]
 [1,]   1*1+3*2   1*3+3*4
 [2,]   2*1+4*2   2*3+4*4
```

I.e. `[1,1]` is a result of sum-product of first row elements (1 and 3) with first column elements (1 and 2): `1*1+3*2`.